# How can I enable video and audio codecs?

Tags: multimedia, codecs

I would like to know how can I enable video and audio codecs not included by default on Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install this package via the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Installing this package will allow you to play MP3 files, and
to decode various audio formats such as LAME. It will also allow you to use Microsoft fonts, install the Java Runtime Environment, Adobe Flash, and play DVDs.

Additional reading: [Restricted Formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), and [Medibuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu#Adding%20the%20Repository).

Answer (score 5):

Run the following in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 4):

To play **encrypted DVDs**, you must install `libdvdread4`, which is a codec allowing you to play them.

- Run this command in a terminal:

  `sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

Comment: on latest Ubuntu (20.10 aka groovy), the package is called libdvdread8

Answer (score 1):

If you want only free & open-source software, then without enabling [Multiverse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Multiverse) repository, you can install following packages which are available on [Universe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Universe) repository:-

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav
```

In which **`gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3`** provides decoding of MPEG 1 audio layer III streams, **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad`** **`gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly`** are the [gstreamer plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GStreamer#Plug-ins) and **`gstreamer1.0-libav1`**  supports a large number of audio and video compression formats through the use of the libav library.