# How can I play mp3 files or videos?

Tags: sound, multimedia, codecs, file-format

I've just installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo g460  with Windows 7. I am not able to play any movie or mp3 file. When I click on a file I'm asked to install a plugin. When I click on the install button nothing happens.

Comment: Please check the following page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable video and audio codecs?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9096/how-can-i-enable-video-and-audio-codecs)

Answer (score 10):

- Install [**ubuntu-restricted-extras**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-restricted-extras) [image: Install ubuntu-restricted-extras]
- Also have a look at [the Ubuntu wiki page on restricted formats](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

Answer (score 1):

Use the terminal and install restricted extras:
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Or just search "Ubuntu Restricted Extras" (or just restricted") in your software center and install the ubuntu restricted (as opposed to xubuntu or kubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

The codecs are not default in Ubuntu so you may need to install them following any of the above links you also could install other players such as VLC player and make it your default, totem and rythmbox also could be updated to have the missing codecs 
cheers

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that you can rely on **GStreamer** packages.

Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search for GStreamer. That's all.

Done.

Or use Fluendo mp3 plugin.