# VLC player wont play AVI or MP4

Tags: vlc, codecs, mp4, avi

I'm brand new to Ubuntu (and linux all together). I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo S10e, and I'm trying to play movies that I loaded from my external HD onto the netbook. I've tried 4 different files, but none are working in either the standard Ubuntu video player or VLC. The only thing that shows up is the VLC cone in the display window.

I have no idea if the graphics driver was installed or not, and if it wasnt I dont know how to do that in Ubuntu.

I have 1.5gb of ram installed, so I doubt thats the issue. Anyways, i'm not very computer saavy, but I'd appreciate any help. Thanks you in advance.

Comment: See  http://askubuntu.com/questions/9096/how-can-i-enable-video-and-audio-codecs  and  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

Answer (score 1):

Avi and MP4 are proprietary formats, so you need to install the Ubuntu Restricted Extras. From the description of the package: "[Installs] Commonly used applications with restricted copyright (mp3, avi, mpeg, TrueType, Java, Flash, Codecs)"

Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search "Ubuntu Restricted Extras"